# Twitter: Why statuses/user_timeline.json returns an empty array?

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, twitter

I want to view another user's timeline and I'm wondering why user_timeline.json returns an empty array? When I don't put parameters it works fine, it shows the authenticated user timeline but I can't see other users timeline when I put the user_id as a parameter. Why?

Here's my code:

```
getUserTimeline: function(id_str) {
    var endpoint_url = CONSTANTS.BASE_URL + 'statuses/user_timeline.json';
    createTwitterSignatureParams('GET', endpoint_url, 'user_id', id_str);
    return $resource(endpoint_url).get({'user_id': id_str}).$promise;
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Just had to change GET by QUERY
$resource(endpoint_url).get(...) ==> $resource(endpoint_url).query(...)